# Java cache and update dynamically

Tags: java, design-patterns, caching, tomcat, servlets

I need to "preload" some data from a database on servlet startup.

So I thought to create some cache e.g. using a `HashMap` or some similar synchronized version.

I also need to update the cache on database update changes.
So I thought to add some kind of "listener".

My question is: is this somehow available or do I have to actually implement it?

If yes what design pattern would be the best approach here?

**Update:**
No JPA or ORM used. But Spring is available

Comment: Are you using a library for persistence?  Most of them support various forms of caching already, no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: No.Direct SQL calls to database

Comment: Does your cache need to be distributed to multiple processes?  Does the write operation need to update other cache instances (or cause them to update) or is it only relevant to the process that is doing the write?

Comment: @philwb:No multiple processes.Only relevant to the process doing the write.

Comment: one more question - how fast does your process need to receive the changes from the db?  Is it long enough that a polling thread could check every minute or do you need effectively a trigger at the db to broadcast the change?

Comment: @philwb:The ideal would be to update the cache immediatelly with the db changes i.e. at any time the cache and the db should be consistent.The "good side" is that the db update is not expected to happen too often.But when it happens these changes should be visible asap

Answer (score 3):

Yes of course you can implement that
I'll draw a small architecture then ill explain it to u:

[image: Architecture diagram]

first of all , you can learn about Mappers  [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) and TDGs [here](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html).
A mapper has a method called **cacheAll()** which calls and delegate to TDG's method  **cacheAll()** which in its turn has a mission to get all rows from a table from the db( the rows you want to cache in the cache object).

so basically first you have to create a listener implementing **"ServletContextListener"**
which means its a listener for the whole servlet context, and inside its **contextInitialized** you have to call **mp.fill(Mapper.cacheAll())**, so it is sthg like ( this is general code, of course write it better and optimize it)

```
public class myServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener{

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        mp.fill(Mapper.cacheAll());
 }

//
}
```

Don't forget to add your listener in web.xml:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>myServletContextListener </listener-class>
</listener>
```

so what this will do , is on startup of the server, will cache all record into a hashmap mp in a cache object.

As for updating cache based on database change, you will have to use [observer pattern](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612).

**UPDATE**
I forgot to mention, about the cache object, i assume you want it accessible for all users or your app, so you should code it as a singleton (singleton pattern), code like that:

```
 public class cacheObject
{
    private static Map cMap;
    private static cacheObject cObject;
    private cacheObject()
    {
        cMap = Mapper.cacheAll();
    }
    public static synchronized cacheObject getInstance()
    {
        if (cObject == null){
            cObject = new cacheObject();
        }
        return cObject;
    }

}
```

Also if the data that you want to cache can be **changed** by users, so make it a **Threadlocal** singleton.

Answer (score 2):

You may find your needs served best by [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) here.  The wiki [article](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CachesExplained) on Caches is probably most relevant to you, but the exact approach here would depend heavily on the conditions for database update changes.  If you want to refresh the whole cache on database update changes -- or at least invalidate old entries -- you might just call `Cache.invalidateAll()` whenever a database update occurs.  If you're willing to let the cache be only slightly behind the times, using `CacheBuilder.refreshAfterWrite(long, TimeUnit)` might work well for you.

Comment: @LuisWasserman:I have never used Guava before.Is it just 1 jar or does it have many dependencies?I ask because the project is rather small.I cannot present e.g. 20 MB extra due to dependencies to other libs

Comment: I believe it has at most one dependency, the (tiny) JSR-305.   That may not even be strictly necessary.  If you're concerned about output JAR size, we recommend http://proguard.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: This is a low complexity approach given your needs and is good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Hashmap and it's thread safe variant ConcurrentHashMap is already available.

There are caching solutions which are available like ehcache which also provide advanced support like eviction policies and many more things.

As for the design pattern, read into the Observer design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I actually had a production level project where I needed to do something like this. My solution was (and this is just MY solution) was to load the object (your so "data") into memory at servlet start up. This decision was made because the object was large enough that it made client requests sluggish to pull it from the database AND I had a small number of concurrent users. Any requests that would change that object's data in the database would also change the in-memory object. You of course would need to use a synchronized object to do this if you are working with a lot of users. If the amount of data is not huge, then you could always pull from the database every time the user requests information about the data.

Good Luck.