# How to update browser cache in java

Tags: java, spring, caching, spring-mvc

I'm trying to implement browser cache in my application, its working fine but I'm not able to add the newly updated part into browser cache. Simply I want to update only that part into the browser cache which is being updated within already existing cache.

Code used for caching is:

```
<bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
    <property name="cacheSeconds" value="2100" />
    <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true" />
    <property name="cacheMappings">
        <props>

            <prop key="/**/*.html">2592000</prop>
            <prop key="/**/*.htm">2592000</prop>
            <prop key="/**/*.jpg">2592000</prop>
            <prop key="/**/*.gif">2592000</prop>
            <prop key="/**/*.css">2592000</prop>
            <prop key="/**/*.js">2592000</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through this link 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9068951/java-cache-and-update-dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I have come across `@Cacheable` annotation available in spring framework. I think that is what exactly you want to achieve. I have never used it in my application but have studied about it.

For further details and example please refere this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.0.M1/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html).

And also there is one more feature from Spring Framework for this called `ShallowETagHeaderFilter`.
Please refere this [link](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.html) to know more about it.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.

Comment: I have tried with that but I'm using Detached Criteria and its not working with Detached Criteria.